# Update all the AWS application instance java Property object when S3 bucket property file updated using REST call

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

**Scenario**:

We have one application deployed in AWS in multiple EC2 instances. We have one property file in S3 bucket referred to in this application. We use this property file and store all data in Property object and used it throughout the application.

When there is any update in S3 bucket property file we call REST endpoint to update java Property object but there is no guarantee by calling this REST endpoint for one time it will update Property object in all instances.

**Question**:  How to update this java Property object values in all EC2 instances when S3 bucket property file gets updated?

```
 public static void load(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try{
        props = //code to get s3 bucket content
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        
        throw new ApplicationException(e);
    }
}
```

This method is getting calling in our endpoint to load new properties.

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_aws_s3_backend exactly for your needs! ;)

Comment: ..but this is only the "s3-end", for **refresh/update ** part, i tried: https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+cloud+config+reload

Comment: bushra-hannure - Does [Netflix/archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius) suits to your requirements ? You can also refer [this blog](https://netflixtechblog.com/announcing-archaius-dynamic-properties-in-the-cloud-bc8c51faf675) for more information.

Comment: these links are not helpful that much because we haven't used spring-cloud config, I have added code snippet we have used for reference.